# jqgrid custom function should return array

Tags: php

Please check following code snippet.
When I enter future date through datepicker in jqgrid add form, then instead of showing validation message as 'Invalid Date Of Birth' other validation message is shown like-'custom function should return array!', please assist me..

```
function checkFamilyDOB(dob){
    var bdate = dob.split('-');

    var today = new Date();
    var d = today.getDate();
    var yr = today.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth();
    var msg = "Invalid Date Of Birth";
    if(yr >= bdate[2] || m >= bdate[1] || d >= bdate[0]) 
    {
      return [false,msg,""];
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe its because of the [], that represents an array.. I might be 100% wrong its just my opinion why can't you just do return msg;

Comment: I would guess that the problem is that when the date is valid then you are not returning an array.  The `if` statement is not run and so there is no return value.  Try something like `return [];` after the `if` statement

Comment: hi, I was not returning anything for correct input... thanks

Comment: If this is still relevant, explain your code further. Why is this question tagged with PHP while it contains code that looks like JS?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkFamilyDOB(dob){
    var bdate = dob.split('-');

    var today = new Date();
    var d = today.getDate();
    var yr = today.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth();
    var msg = "Invalid Date Of Birth";
    if(yr >= bdate[2] || m >= bdate[1] || d >= bdate[0]) 
    {
      return [false,msg];
    }
    return [true];
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

I think, it cuz of short array() syntax  (ex: [1,2,3]). It doesn't work in PHP 5.3
You should upgrade your PHP to 5.4 or use array(1,2,3) syntax, 
i mean:

```
return array('value1', 'value2');
```

Sorry, if i wrong

Comment: Are you sure about that single line? Does the rest of that code look like PHP to you?